# Is inverted aerial refeuling possible?

Tags: mid-air-refueling, inverted-flight

Google found lots of information about how to air-to-air refuel an inverted plane inside a video game.  Is it possible in reality?

Comment: This could be potentially a good idea for some airplanes. Some jet fighters were known to be very difficult to plug in the refueling pipe and it may take many test flights to figure out the best way of doing it, some of which turned out to be real bizarre. If flying inverted is the solution then so be it.

Answer (score 2):

Any of the large tanker aircraft like a KC-135, KC-10, KC-46, KC-130, etc can't sustain inverted flight, so those would be out.

The most likely case would be a tactical aircraft refueling another with a "buddy pod" setup. The US Navy uses S-3 aircraft, and before they retired, A-6 aircraft, for this mission. ***If*** the plumbing was set up in the tanker aircraft to pick up fuel from the top of the tank, then this could probably work. Whether any of those aircraft are ***actually*** plumbed to do that, would be a question for an S-3, A-6, or now-a-days an F/A-18 driver.

Since there's no conceivable utility to accomplishing such a procedure, I rather doubt any designers put extra effort or expense into enabling it.

All that said, nothing much would prevent the tanker & receiver from continuing the refueling during a barrel roll, which maintains positive G throughout, so for a moment, you'd be refueling while inverted, just without negative G's.  Again, no value in doing that, but to be able to say "*they were refueling while inverted*" then that's probably the easiest way to do it.

EDIT:

If only the receiver is inverted, the issues would be different. Refueling with a boom & receptacle wouldn't work, since the receptacle is on the top of the receiver. With a probe & drogue, the pilot of the receiver would probably have almost none of the tanker aircraft in view - rather than it being visible "above" him through his canopy, it's now obscured by the nose and the floor of his own aircraft. Flying formation on only a drogue sounds hard; flying formation on just a hose (ie after the drogue is attached to the probe) sounds impossible.

Comment: The question is for an inverted aircraft receiving fuel.  I was thinking the tanker would probably be upright.  Unusual tanker attitudes are interesting, though.

Comment: The point about the boom makes sense.  I do not find your explanation of probe and drogue convincing.  For a KC-130, the drogue is off center.  An inverted receiver might be able to view the KC-130 by looking to the side, where these is no nose.  The F-16 cockpit has a pretty good field of view, and nose cameras (EFVS) are a thing that exists.  Maybe the F-35 AN/AAQ-37 DAS would be sufficient for formation flying?

Comment: https://media.cnn.com/api/v1/images/stellar/prod/200706105211-voyager-refueling.jpg?q=w_1015,c_fill/f_webp